# Pressing a "cancel" popup button in playwright throws exception

Tags: python, playwright

I use playwright in python to cancel a text-submission on a webpage:

```
page.once("dialog", lambda dialog: asyncio.create_task(dialog.accept()))
with page.expect_navigation():
    page.click("text=\"Cancel\"")
```

However this throws:

```
Exception in callback SyncBase._sync.<locals>.callback(<Task finishe...> result=None>) at /home/.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/sync_base.py:100
handle: <Handle SyncBase._sync.<locals>.callback(<Task finishe...> result=None>) at /home/.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/sync_base.py:100>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
...
TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got None
```

The code works fine, the cancel gets confirmed correctly - however it'd be nice to know what I'm doing wrong here and how to fix it.

Comment: Wild guess, but maybe it should be just `lambda dialog: dialog.accept()` (without `asyncio.create_task()`)? I can't find any documentation for the Python version of `page.once()`, so it's hard to be sure.

Comment: That was it. Good eye. I have to agree on the documentation. It seems to not exist for the python version. If you submit the solution as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Maybe we can get rid of the lambda entirely? (As we are down to "lambda dialog: dialog.accept()")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```py
page.once("dialog", lambda dialog: asyncio.create_task(dialog.accept()))
```

It should apparently be just:

```py
page.once("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept())
```

This was basically a lucky guess, so take it with a grain of salt. I can't find a good source to back it up.

At the time of writing, the [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/playwright-python/) for the Python version of Playwright doesn't seem to mention `page.once()` at all.

In the original JavaScript version of Playwright, `page.once()` is documented as part of the standard Node.js [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) class, from which `Page` is derived. Nothing like `EventEmitter` exists in the Python standard library, though.

Comment: A comment on the question OP asked if this also means you can get rid of the `lambda`. I don't think so, since you need it to accept the `dialog` argument given to you by Playwright.

Comment: I've asked around on IRC and it seems that `page.once("dialog", operators.methodcaller('accept'))` would be an option. I have however kept the `lambda` as I consider it more readable.